# Why I got Remove Disks or other media press any key to restart every time I reboot?

Tags: windows-10

I got that error every time I reboot my computer.

The error is "Remove Disks or other media press any key to restart"

Notice I got press any key to restart. I saw people have similar error where they have to press ctrl alt del.

I can just press any key and get into windows.

But I want that computer to reboot smoothly like every other computer

That computer used to have MBR problem. I fixed that. And now I got that message.

The bios is set to boot from SSD that contains windows. There is a USB that hold bitlocker key. It's the same setup with all my other computers.

Comment: Out of curiosity - is there a USB HDD / flash disk that is connected to the PC? (and maybe the BIOS is set to boot from USB first?)

Comment: The bios is set to boot from SSD that contains windows. There is a USB that hold bitlocker key. It's the same setup with all my other computers.

Comment: If I remove bitlocker and the USB I still ahve the same error

Answer (score 1):

The computer tries to boot form the  USB drive containing your key.

To fix that, enter the BIOS and make sure again that the first boot device is your SSD and then look for 'boot from removable' and 'boot from other devices' and select them both to disable.

Comment: I did that. Obviously.

Comment: Disabling secure boot will also fix that but it's not possible in your case. Try also disabling quick boot if it's on. Also make sure the USB device itself is connected when you save your boot order.

Comment: how to disable secure boot?

Comment: It is also an option in the BIOS/EFI.